# Magmi Images not working correct

Tags: magento, magmi

According to the magmi documentation you add a "+" sign before the base image if you want to include it in the media gallery.

I have done this but for some reason when I upload my additional media images the base image does not show in the media gallery with the media images.

Please help I have never had this problem before and I am not sure how to correct it.

The Magmi documentation for this can be seen here http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Image_attributes_processor

Also when I import the media images the base image no longer shows on the backend but the base image still shows as the main image on the frontend.

I am on magento 1.8.1.0 with the newest php patch

Comment: This may be part of the Magento 1.8.x magmi compatiblity issues i have to investigate. Magmi is "mostly" compatible with 1.8.x but i didn't have time to check full compatiblity yet. Thanks for reporting this strange behaviour

Comment: Has this issue been corrected?

Comment: I'm using magmi for images import on 1.8.1.x and without this issue, it will be somewhere else.